# Initial Aegir Setup

Tags: multi-sites, aegir

This might be a dumb question, but the [Aegir](http://community.aegirproject.org/installing) install instructions do not mention installing Drupal first. I am wondering if that matters at all?

Should Drupal 6 be installed separately from Aegir, and in what location? Sorry if this is obvious, but perhaps I am missing something small?

Thanks,

KM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to install Aegir, the [(recommended) automated](http://community.aegirproject.org/installing/debian) way using a debian package or the [manual (though mostly automated still) method](http://community.aegirproject.org/installing/manual). Both methods take care of downloading and installing Drupal 6 and all needed contrib modules and other libraries.